# Cannot find module '@angular/core', but still can be built

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I am using asp.net core,typescript and angular2 for building a website. IDE is Visual studio 2015 Update3.

The issues:

[image]

Error message:

1. cannot find module '@angular/core'
2. Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning.

***But the project still can be built successed.***

I have two projects using the same code structure and this issue only happens in one project.

Have any idea? Thanks!

**tsconfig.json**

{

```
"compilerOptions": {

  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,

  "experimentalDecorators": true,

  "module": "commonjs",

  "noEmitOnError": false,

  "noImplicitAny": false,

  "removeComments": false,

  "sourceMap": true,

  "target": "es5",

  "moduleResolution": "node"

},

"exclude": [

  "wwwroot",

  "node_modules"

  //"typings/index.d.ts"

],

"compileOnSave": true
```

}

package.json

{

```
"version": "1.0.1",

"name": "asp.net",

 "private": true,

 "scripts": {

 "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",

 "lite": "lite-server",

 "postinstall": "typings install",

 "tsc": "tsc",

 "tsc:w": "tsc -w",

 "typings": "typings"

},

 "license": "ISC",

"dependencies": {

  "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",

  "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",

  "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",

  "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",

  "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",

  "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",

  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",

  "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",

  "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",

  "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",

  "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",

  "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",

  "core-js": "^2.4.0",

  "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",

  "systemjs": "0.19.27",

  "zone.js": "^0.6.12"

},

"devDependencies": {

  "gulp": "^3.9.1",

  "gulp-clean": "0.3.2",

  "gulp-jshint": "2.0.1",

  "gulp-uglify": "1.5.4",

  "gulp-uglifycss": "1.0.6",

  "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",

  "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",

  "jshint": "2.9.2",

  "jshint-stylish": "2.2.0",

  "pump": "1.0.1"

}
```

}

***Update:***

I copied the same codes to a new project. everything works fine.

***how can the project recognise the variable @angular and know which folder should be found?***

**Update:**

I fixed this issue, but i don't know why.
there was a folder named 'src' under 'project/bin' folder. the src folder contains some DLL files. The DLL files cannot be deleted because "*the source file names are larger than is supported by the file system"*, after i change the name shorter and delete the folder src. This issue is fixed.

Comment: Can you update post with your tsconfig.json and package.json?

Comment: You need to install typings for `rx` and `rx-lite`, to make the `Promise` error disappear.  https://github.com/typings/typings. I may post a more complete answer tomorrow, its late now

Comment: Hi, updated the post, @gnalck

Comment: @Tseng, not the Promise issue, that's can not find the module

Comment: Because the runtime validation can't validate the modules which use rx for promises. Just try installing typings tools and then run `typings install dt~rx`, `typings install dt~rx-lite` and possibly `typings install dt~angular2` or `typings install dt~@angular`

Comment: You also may need to target `es6` in your tsconfig

Comment: @Tseng, Es6 also doesn't work,  I created a new project and copied the same codes to the new project. That's works.

Comment: Are you using ReSharper by any chance?

Comment: @HuseinRoncevic Is ReSharper integrated in VS?  i don't use that.